# Creating Twitter threads when replying

Tags: twitter, tweet

I'm trying to work out if there is a proper tool on Twitter that allows you to create Twitter "threads" when replying to someone else?

I found out a [way to do it](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-make-a-thread-on-twitter-4689054) when making your own thread via the Twitter thread tool, but this tool doesn't seem to be available when replying to others?

Is the only way to do it is manually by replying to each post one after the other (as the suggested alternative in this linked article)?

I've up until now just been making all my responses as a reply to the parent item, but I think this can make it hard to follow and if you click on one of the replies (such as the first one) then you don't see the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possible ways to do it:

1. **the obvious way** - reply to the tweet and then reply to your own reply and so on. The problem with this method is that if, while you're busy typing a reply to one of your your replies someone else manages to reply to the same reply you're replying to, the thread chain will break.
2. **the clever way** - instead of actually making a thread as a reply and risk having it broken by someone else's reply, you can begin the first tweet of your thread by quoting the tweet you would have otherwise reply to. This way you guarantee that you're the owner of the thread, that means you can continue threading more tweets to it even after some time.
3. **the hybrid way** - like in method No. 2, you quote the tweet you wish to reply to and thread as many tweets necessary. Copy the URL of the thread you just did. Then, you comment the tweet you wish to answer with an appealing resume of your thread and paste the link to your thread at the end. The result is a comment that is among all the other comments, in it a teaser for a long and detailed read for those who are interested. This way you enjoy both worlds... on the one hand, a detailed coherent thread for your followers + a comment to the original tweet available for all those who participate in the conversation.

Comment: Thanks. I've so far just been doing it the "option 1" method, but to avoid the issue you mentioned I generally type out my text in advance and then paste it in quite quickly one after the other; but doing this on mobile isn't very easy haha.... as for option 2, the major difference I see with that is, a standard reply in the thread remains in context within the thread and can be seen by everyone amongst the discussion, whilst a _quote tweet_ would only been seen by your followers or who gets notified about it and won't appear in the original thread itself.

Comment: Then go with a hybrid. I edited my answer to explain about the hybrid in more detail...